# Everything inside one docker container or specialized containers

Tags: deployment, docker

I have been reading about Docker for a long time and tried few examples. While going through blogs, I didn't find any unanimous answer as whether a product having multiple components like JEE deployables, database, webserver etc should be deployed, in one single container or on different containers. Can someone please provide detailed answer in terms of

1. Manageability
2. Complexity
3. Risk (like data loss, security etc.)
4. Any other point, welcome

Also will it be worth going Kubernetes route or Docker is still sufficient?

Comment: There is no unique answer to this topic, it can depend upon many things. It may help if you add details like the softwares you want to launch, the ports used, the file systems mounted...  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

There are alternative views (that may work well depending on your use case) but the official docker stance is [one process per container](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#run-only-one-process-per-container). From my experience, you'll be able to fit into the docker ecosystem and re-use things more effectively if you go with the grain on that one. However, there are alternative solutions (again, that may work well depending on your use case) such as [passenger-docker](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker).